# I am using twitter bootstrap i want to hide the vertical line when mobile screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to hide the vertical line when mobile screen using twitter bootstrap

```
.mycontent-left {
      border-right: 1px dashed #333;
    }

    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">
        <div class="mycontent-left">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span6">
        <div class="mycontent-right">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use media query as hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859566/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-change-css-class-based-on-media-defined-widths).

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .mycontent-left {
      border-right: 1px dashed #333;
    }
}
```

You may experiment and change your markup to something like:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6 mycontent-left">
          left
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
        right
      </div>
</div>
```

Here is one [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13001/) for you.

I would also friendly recommend you to get familiar with the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) that bootstap introduces as well as with its [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).